# [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.auth.FacebookAuthProvider is not a constructor"

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

i am trying to implement social login with firebase and vuejs, but i am having this error message.
[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: this.auth.FacebookAuthProvider is not a constructor"

```
enter code here   
facebookLogin () {
      // Sign in using a popup.
      var provider = new this.auth.FacebookAuthProvider()
      provider.addScope('user_birthday')
      this.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function (result) {
        // This gives you a Facebook Access Token.
        var token = result.credential.accessToken
        // The signed-in user info.
        console.log(token)
        var user = result.user
        console.log(user)
      })
    }
```

Comment: Please provide more code. The problem is `this.auth`. Did you import the firebase library correctly and assigned it to this.auth?

Comment: Thanks alot.. I did solve the problem, the issue was with how I imported the firebase module..